Hyperledger Fabric in ARM Cortex processor (for NVIDIA Jetson Orin)
anybody has successfully deployed a fabric network on ARM Cortex processor? (Specifically on this hardware : https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/autonomous-machines/embedded-systems/jetson-orin/ ) I am not sure if there are any images available that I could use on that platform.
Could this approach be valid to build the images?
https://www.polarsparc.com/xhtml/Hyperledger-ARM-Build.html
